# Which term, "precious" or "valuable," is more appropriate?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

There are various ways to express gratitude for someone's time. Which term, "precious" or "valuable," is more appropriate?

Thank you for your **precious** time.

Thank you for your **valuable** time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either should be fine.  But I'd probably use neither.  It looks slightly sarcastic.

Especially "your precious time", makes it seem as if the other person is always complaining about not having enough time, even though everyone else is just as busy as they are.

So "Thank you for your time".  Seems to be formal and polite.

Comment: *Precious* sounds very... precious.